# proftpd limit write to directory with user defined message

Tags: linux, configuration, ftp-server

I am attempting to specify a directory on my proftpd server that should not allow users to upload files to a specific directory. During an update i do not want anything to be written to this directory, but more importantly, i want a meaningful message to be returned to the user. I have discovered that i can define this in the configuration.

```
  <Directory /my/restricted/folder>
    <Limit ALL>
      DenyAll
    </Limit>

    <Limit READ>
      AllowAll
    </Limit>

  </Directory>
```

But is it possible to also define a specific error message to return to the user. Something along the lines of "I am sorry, you cant currently upload to this directory. System upgrade in progress".

If this is not possible, can anyone give me a different idea of how to accomplish a meaningful rejection when a user attempts an upload on a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Proftpd unfortunately does not provide this functionality natively. You could modify your Proftpd config at each maintenance window to provide this info in the welcome message and prevent writing to the directory in question.